# Assertion in sahi script for masked password

Tags: passwords, assertion, sahi

How can we apply assertion in a sahi script to check whether password field is showing masked value? For example, `**********`

Answer (score 1):

Get the type attribute from the input and check that it is equal to "password":

```
_assertEqual(_textbox("myTextBox").getAttribute("TYPE"), "password")
```

EDIT: To avoid confusion and based on Narayan's comment below, the correct way to do this is actually:

```
_assertExists(_password("id"))
```

Comment: Psych, the password field won't be identified as _textbox. If the type is password, it will be identified as _password. So checking _assertExists(_password("id")) is enough.